# Custom Windows Control library in C#

Tags: c#, custom-controls

How can I implement **small task features** in my own custom windows control library like below?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own designer for your control.  Start that by adding a reference to System.Design.  A sample control could look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
public class MyControl : Control {
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Note the [Designer] attribute, it sets the custom control designer.  To get yours started, derive your own designer from ControlDesigner.  Override the ActionLists property to create the task list for the designer:

```
internal class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner {
    private DesignerActionListCollection actionLists;
    public override DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists {
        get {
            if (actionLists == null) {
                actionLists = new DesignerActionListCollection();
                actionLists.Add(new MyActionListItem(this));
            }
            return actionLists;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to create your custom ActionListItem, that could look like this:

```
internal class MyActionListItem : DesignerActionList {
    public MyActionListItem(ControlDesigner owner)
        : base(owner.Component) {
    }
    public override DesignerActionItemCollection GetSortedActionItems() {
        var items = new DesignerActionItemCollection();
        items.Add(new DesignerActionTextItem("Hello world", "Category1"));
        items.Add(new DesignerActionPropertyItem("Checked", "Sample checked item"));
        return items;
    }
    public bool Checked {
        get { return ((MyControl)base.Component).Prop; }
        set { ((MyControl)base.Component).Prop = value; }
    }
}
```

Building the list in the GetSortedActionItems method is the key to creating your own task item panel.

That's the happy version.  I should note that I crashed Visual Studio to the desktop three times while working on this example code.  VS2008 is *not* resilient to unhandled exceptions in the custom designer code.  Save often.  Debugging design time code requires starting another instance of VS that can stop the debugger on the design-time exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a "Smart Tag". You can find a quick example of it here:

> [**Adding Smart Tags to Windows Forms Controls**](http://code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0707081)

> **Source:** [How can I implement "small task features" in my own custom windows control library like below? - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/127782/How-can-I-implement-small-task-features-in-my-own-.aspx#answer1)