# How do I add Windows Form Designer support to a custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, ide

I am new to the concept of custom controls, and until recently my experience has been limited to extending controls that already exists.

In Visual Studio, how do I add support for my custom controls in the form of Designer Drop Downs and forms?

This picture below identifies the kind of components I am wishing to create for my custom controls.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Windows Control library in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186953/custom-windows-control-library-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend reading [Extending Design Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx) on MSDN.  In this case, you want a custom designer for your type, which can be specified via the [DesignerAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute.aspx) decorating the type.  For details, see [Custom Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h51z5c0x.aspx).