# How to add designer support to Winforms extension control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

I'm creating a Windows form application using C# and the .Net 5.0 framework, and would like to create an extension class of the button control that I can use as menu controls, which is to say clicking one of the buttons will open a corresponding page ("page" being a custom interface I made for UserControls to implement rather than making each piece of my application a separate form).

However, after making my MenuBtn class, which extends the Button class, I get a very long error when trying to drag the MenuBtn from my VS 2019 toolbox to Designer view. **It seems that I need to add some sort of design time support to my MenuBtn class but I'm not sure how to do that.** I know I can use the class programmatically, but I would like to be able to use the control in the designer.

I'm aware that I could just create a UserControl wrapper around a button and use that instead, but because Buttons already have nearly all of the functionality I want, doing that seems like bad design. Also, I'm creating this as a sort of framework, so that future apps I make can use these menu buttons. That's why I'm not just creating a custom OnClick event handler for each button that opens a specific page.

Below is a snippet of my MenuBtn class, which is very simple right now, and a link to a picture of the error I receive when trying to place the MenuBtn into the design window from the toolbox (I cant copy and paste from the error window and its a long error). As you can see from the code snippet, I've tried adding a designer tag to the class.

```
    [Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
    public partial class MenuBtn : Button
    {
        public MenuBtn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

**Designer error Message:** [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWS82.jpg)

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186953/custom-windows-control-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: I did come across that question previously, the issue is I don't need any custom designer functionality, the standard button functionality is fine, I just can't place it from my toolbox. I did try that solution but it didnt make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what the issue was, I'm still a little bewildered, but I was able to resolve the issue by some combination of cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and changing the build target CPU from Any cpu to x86, and then back again.

I guess the issue was not that I needed to add some sort of designer support, but a problem with the toolbox/designer reading from the dll of my project.